# Virtualbox 6.1.10 not recognizing USB connections

Tags: networking, usb, virtualbox, virtualization

Ubuntu host windows guest.

So I have virtualbox 6.10.10 installed, and I installed the `Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack v. 6.1.10r138449` and have tried setting the to both `USB 3.0 (xHCI) Controller` and `USB 2.0 (OHCI = EHCI) Controller` option on for the vm in the hopes of connecting a USB to the guest. I am using a lenovo l480 with a `USB 3.1` port.

When I try to click the icon adding usbs within the USB settings for the VM it does not detect any, and I have plugged a USB in, and the host system detects it just fine.

```
lsusb                                      
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology DataTraveler 100 G3/G4/SE9 G2
...
```

running

```
wmic path CIM_LogicalDevice where "Description like 'USB%'" get /value
```

on the guest shows the possible USB 3.0 connections, so I would assume that the VM instance is working. However, I am not certain.

I have not added a filter, which I assume is correct. If I try, it too provides no pre-filled values in the form.

`groups`

```
jonas adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare fuse
```

after running `sudo usermod -aG vboxusers jonas` and logging out

```
jonas adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare vboxusers fuse
```

Comment: Did you log out?

Comment: Maybe you needed to logout after you installed the Extension Pack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your user to `vboxusers` group. With some VB versions it isn't done automatically for some reason.

Run:

```
sudo usermod -aG vboxusers $USER
```

then log off and on.